# Deserialize a list of objects from Json Http response

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, httpresponse

I have my JSON Response like that:

```
{
  "Adddress": [
    {
      "Country": "United States",
      "City": "Irmo",
      "Line1": "103 Kinley Rd",
      "Line2": null,
      "PostalCode": "20063",
      "State": "SC",
      "AddressCode": "BILL-01"
    },
    {
      "Country": "United States",
      "City": "Irmo",
      "Line1": "1098 Kanley Road",
      "Line2": "Building B",
      "PostalCode": "29063",
      "State": "SC",
      "AddressCode": "SHIP-01"
    }]
}
```

َAnd Here is my Address Class:

```
 [JsonObject()]
    public class Address
    {
        public string AddressCode { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have this C# Code to deserialize this http response to my object list:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Adddress>().Result;//JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RestResponse>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);//
    foreach (var d in dataObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.Country);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TestREST.Program+RestResponse]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'RestResponse', line 2, position 19.

What should I do with it to make my deserilization work ?

Comment: Please post your `Address` class.

Comment: Updated with Address Class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Adddress` is single, the json you get in is an array of addresses *(so more then one)*, you have to deserialize it into e.g. `AddressList` that contains more then one address

```
string json = "{\"Adddress\":[{\"Country\":\"United States\",\"City\":\"Irmo\",\"Line1\":\"103 Kinley Rd\",\"Line2\":null,\"PostalCode\":\"20063\",\"State\":\"SC\",\"AddressCode\":\"BILL - 01\"},{\"Country\":\"United States\",\"City\":\"Irmo\",\"Line1\":\"1098 Kanley Road\",\"Line2\":\"Building B\",\"PostalCode\":\"29063\",\"State\":\"SC\",\"AddressCode\":\"SHIP - 01\"}]}";

 var dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddressList>(json);
 foreach (var d in dataObjects.Adddress)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.Country);
 }
```

Classes:

```
public class Adddress
{
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("City")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Line1")]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Line2")]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("PostalCode")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("State")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("AddressCode")]
    public string AddressCode { get; set; }
}

public class AddressList
{
    [JsonProperty("Adddress")]
    public IList<Adddress> Adddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The Json that I get does not have "\" this.  I have the exact same string but without backslashes and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pouyan the ` \ ` is to escape the ` " ` characters. Because i just wrote the string inside c# code itself *(my example doesn't get the json data from a server)* ... works perfectly btw